# Debian 7.1: duplicity error when using gdocs backend

Tags: debian, backup, python, duplicity

I've installed `duplicity` backup tool plus `python-gdata` library on my debian 7.1 amd64 system.

When I want to use `duplicity` to store my documents on Google Drive, it shows this error after asking for my password:

```
BackendException: Error while fetching remote entries: 'DocsClient' object has no attribute 'get_everything'.
```

This is the command I run:

```
duplicity documents/ gdocs://my_user_name@gmail.com
```

when I add `--verbose debug` option, this is the error:

```
Using temporary directory /tmp/duplicity-fgU3N8-tempdir
Backend error detail: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1404, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1397, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1248, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1007, in ProcessCommandLine
    backup, local_pathname = set_backend(args[0], args[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line900, in set_backend
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(bend)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 158, in get_backend
    return _backends[pu.scheme](pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/gdocsbackend.py", line 62, in __init__
    entries = self.__fetch_entries(parent_folder_id, 'folder', folder_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/gdocsbackend.py", line 245, in __fetch_entries
    self.__handle_error('Error while fetching remote entries: %s.' % str(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/gdocsbackend.py", line 182, in __handle_error
    raise BackendException(message)
BackendException: Error while fetching remote entries: 'DocsClient' object has no attribute 'get_everything'.
```

duplicity is version 0.6.18-3

does it have something to do with Google Docs becoming Google Drive? could it be that API or urls have changes since then? Debian software is pretty old, so this could be.

If so, what can I do to make duplicity work?

Edit:

I just installed duplicity version 0.6.22 and `gdata` in a virtualenv. I enter the same username and password as before, but the error message changed to this:

```
BackendException: Invalid user credentials given. Be aware that accounts that use 2-step verification require creating an application specific access code for using this Duplicity backend. Follow the instrucction in http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&topic=1056286 and create your application-specific password to run duplicity backups.
```

I'm just trying duplicity, but as I understand deja-dup which is ubuntu's primary backup tool is based on duplicity. Is duplicity a reliable backup tool?

Comment: Thank you. It worked, I was missing the `/dir` part, and looks like it was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it have something to do with Google Docs becoming Google Drive?

Check this interesting bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1030868

> could it be that API or urls have changes since then?

Is very likely.

> If so, what can I do to make duplicity work?

There is a fix in the way. You should wait till is committed to the main branch, then request for it to be backported to Debian (that if they like to do so) so you can install it in stable. Otherwise building the package yourself once the Fix is released.

> I just installed duplicity version 0.6.22 and gdata in a virtualenv. I enter the same username and password as before, but the error [...]

Are you sure you are doing things the right way? I have 0.6.21 and the only error is about "Google Docs backend requires Google Data APIs Python Client Library", that has nothing to do with credentials. You must be sure that you write gdocs://user:pass@gmail.com/dir

Comment: I tried 0.6.22 with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it have something to do with Google Docs becoming Google Drive?

Very likely as the [Google Docs API is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/?csw=1):

> **Important**: Version 3 of the Google Documents List API has been officially deprecated as of September 14, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to move to the Google Drive API.

I didn't bother to look up their deprecation policy, but it not working a year after deprecation would surprise me not at all.

Answer (score 1):

The python-gdata on Ubuntu 12.04 is  2.0.14-2, this is outdated.
Download latest python-gdata deb from http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-gdata/python-gdata_2.0.18+dfsg-1_all.deb and then run

```
dpkg -i python-gdata_2.0.18+dfsg-1_all.deb
```